# I'm unable to used drop_na() function for a data.frame object

Tags: r, raster-functions

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(mapview)

# species name Quercus leucotrichophora

gbif("Quercus", "leucotrichophora", download = T)

sp1 <- gbif("Quercus", "leucotrichophora", geo=T, download = T) #  download is essebtial for data.frame

class(sp1) # object is a data.frame

dim(sp1)

# extract only lat long columns
spg <- sp1%>%select( lon,lat)
```

The  error it is throwing is as follows:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :    unable to find an
> inherited method for function ‘select’ for signature ‘"data.frame"

Comment: try `dplyr::select()`

Answer (score 1):

Where has the `gbif` function come from? Oh, maybe its `dismo` (you didn't mention this in your question):

```
> library(dismo)
Loading required package: raster
Loading required package: sp

Attaching package: ‘raster’

The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’:

    select
```

and because that's attached `raster` that has masked the `select` from `dplyr`.

But that's okay, you should never use `select` from `dplyr` anyway, instead get columns in the usual R way:

```
> spg = sp1[,c("lon","lat")]
> head(spg)
       lon      lat
1 79.65582 29.46042
2 82.48634 28.09335
3 79.53100 29.36000
4 78.35500 30.67417
```

Comment: Yeah, gbif () is from dismo package... thank you it helped